# I made a bubble sort for a list in c and I want to know if I made any particular mistakes

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

It seems to work,but I want to know if a particular situation would make my algorithm crash.Does anyone have any ideas of hidden particular cases,that my program would not cover?
I know it's not the proper way to sort a list,but this is what I had to do.

```
struct Student {
    float medie;
    char nrMatricol[10];
    char *nume;
    char facltate[6];


};
struct Nod{
    Student stud;
    Nod* next;
};
Nod* inserareNodEnd(Nod *l,Student st)
{
    Nod *nou = (Nod*)malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    nou->next = NULL;//NOU->NEXT=0
    nou->stud = st;
    if (!l) {
        //lista este goala
        return nou;
    }
    else
    {
     //lista contine un nod
        Nod *t = l;
        while (t->next) {
            t = t->next;
        }
        t->next = nou;
        return l;
    }

}

Nod * interschimbare(Nod *l, Nod *pred) {
    Nod *aux=l;
    //Nod *auxPred = pred;
    //Nod *auxPredNext =pred->next;
    if (pred) {
        //caz general
        Nod *p, *q, *r;
        pred = pred->next;
        q = p->next;
        r = q->next;
        pred->next = q;
        p->next = r;
        q->next = p;
    }
    else {
        //interschimb noduri 1 cu 2
        Nod *p, *q;
        p = l->next;
        q = p->next;
        l->next = q;
        l = p;


    }
    return l;
}
Nod* sortareBubble(Nod* l) {
char dinNou; // flag interschimb noduri

if (!l && !l->next)
    return l; //lista trebuie sa contina cel putin 2 noduri

do {
    dinNou = 0; // 0 -> ipoteza fara interschimb
    Nod *tmp = l, *pred = 0;
    while (tmp->next) {
        if (tmp->stud.medie > tmp->next->stud.medie) {
            l = interschimb(l, pred);
            dinNou = 1;
            if (pred) {
                pred = pred->next;
            }
            else {
                pred = l;
            }
        }
        else {
            pred = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

} while (dinNou == 1);

return l;
```

}

Comment: Did you test your code? It seems that you sort by mark average. Does it work?

Comment: it worked for my values ,but I want to know if it would be possible to have some undiscovered cases

Comment: Consider posting to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Your code is invalid C. Check your compiler settings if you do not want to compile C++.

Comment: why is invalid in C?

Comment: The types `Student` and `Nod` do not exist. In C, defining a `struct Student` does not "pull" the identifier `Student` to the "regular" name space.

Comment: In `interschimbare` `caz general`, p is not assigned, but it is used. The first if should be `if (!l || !l->next)` . To check for errors, make sure the code can swap the first two nodes of a list, the last two nodes of a list, and two nodes somewhere in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You use `dinNou` (again) to check whether you need to enter again into the cycle. The cycle is a `do`-`while` and `dinNou` is initialized with 0 and if a change occurs, then it will be modified to 1. Essentially, you do the change until there was no change. You have a mistake leading to an inifite loop at

```
while (tmp->next);
```

This will be false if `tmp` (which was initialized to `l`) happens to have no `next` element. Otherwise it will repeatedly ask whether there is a `next` element and since there is no change, it will always be true, leading to an infinite loop. What you did want in my opinion is to use the block following the `while` as the operation set to be done `while` `tmp` has `next`. To achieve that, simply remove the semi-colon:

```
while (tmp->next)
```

After you do that, inside the loop you check whether the average mark of the current student is greater than the next. If so, then you call `interschimbare` (swap) and set `dinNou` to 1. This also seems to be incorrect. If the two neighboring values have to be swapped, then `interschimbare` of `tmp` and `tmp->next` should be called. As a result, you do not really need the `pred` variable and you will need to set `tmp` to `tmp->next` regardless of whether a swap was done or not. Or even better, you can break the loop if a swap occurred.

Comment: @CovrigGeorge-Manuel it is much better, but it still does not seem to be correct. You will need to use a debugger and test your code. Your thoughts which can be found from the code are correct, but there are bugs. If you debug it for an hour or two, you should be able to fix all the problems.